# How to only set OnPlatform for a specific platform?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am programming with Xamarin.Forms. I would like know how to only set the height request for a single platform, using `OnPlatform` in XAML? I want to keep the default value of `-1` if the platform is not referred.

I currently have the following code:

```xml
<ListView.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="WPF" Value="153" />
        <On Platform="Android" Value="-1" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="-1" />
        <On Platform="UWP" Value="-1" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ListView.HeightRequest>
```

I wish I only had to write something like:

```xml
<ListView.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="WPF" Value="153" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ListView.HeightRequest>
```

This doesn't work, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write the platforms with same value in one line:

```
<ListView.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="WPF" Value="153" />
        <On Platform="Android,iOS,UWP" Value="-1" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ListView.HeightRequest>
```

Refer: [Providing platform-specific values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device#providing-platform-specific-values)

Answer (score 1):

This is something that would be easier to do from xaml.cs

**Xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView".....
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
if(Device.RuntimePlatform ==Device.WPF)
myListView.HeightRequest=153;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Default` platform value, that should serve exactly that purpose (did not get to try it, though)

```xml
<ListView.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="WPF" Value="153" />
        <On Platform="Default" Value="-1" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ListView.HeightRequest>
```

Comment: Have you tested it? It doesn't work on the latest version of XF.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //How to change Frame CornerRadius for Android and IOS both at same time in .xaml file

          <Frame Padding="0"
               BorderColor="Green"
               HeightRequest="150"
               WidthRequest="150"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <Frame.CornerRadius>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single">
                        <On Platform="iOS"
                    Value="75" />
                        <On Platform="Android, WinPhone, Windows"
                    Value="80" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Frame.CornerRadius>
                <Image x:Name="ImgUserProfilePic"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   WidthRequest="50"
                   HeightRequest="50">
                </Image>
            </Frame>


    
    //How to change Stacklayout Margin for Android and IOS both at same time in .xaml file      
    
     <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label x:Name="lblVaccineStatus" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="AppFontBold" FontSize="9" Margin="0,-10,0,0"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#3D9E5D" />
                <StackLayout.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS"
        Value="-3" />
                        <On Platform="Android, WinPhone, Windows"
        Value="0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </StackLayout.Margin>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MyProfile_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
```